# Multiply ID mapping throw BaseEntity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm mapping classes via Hibernate and I need to map multiple ID for `Relationship`. 
All ID's extend from `BaseEntity`. How can I implement multiple ID mapping for `Relationship` which contains Foreign Key for `User` in DataBase ?

Basicly fields `userIdOne` and `userIdTwo` in `Relationship` has to contain user's id which send request.

`User` extend own ID from `BaseEntity`.

Each time I run it - get en error:

> This class [class com.mylov.springsocialnetwork.model.Relationship]
>   does not define an IdClass

```java
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @MappedSuperclass
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

    }


    @Builder
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"posts"}, callSuper = false)
    @Entity
    public class User extends BaseEntity {
        private String userName;
        private String realName;
        private String email;
        private String phoneNumber;
        private LocalDate birthDate;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userPosted")
        private Set<Post> posts = new HashSet<>();
        private String password;

        public User(Long id, String userName, String realName, String email, String phoneNumber, LocalDate birthDate,
                    Set<Post> posts, String password) {
            super(id);
            this.userName = userName;
            this.realName = realName;
            this.email = email;
            this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
            this.birthDate = birthDate;
            this.posts = posts;
            this.password = password;
        }
    }


    @Builder
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    public class Relationship implements Serializable {

        //@Id not working
        private Long userIdFrom;
        //@Id
        private Long userIdTo;

        @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
        private RelationshipStatus status;
        private LocalDate friendsRequestDate;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are looking to establish a `Relationship` between two different users. This would mean that each `Relationship` is an object/entity of its own and should have its very own `@Id` (unrelated to user IDs).
The linkage to each `User` that form part of this `Relationship` should be mapped as foreign keys instead (probably `@ManyToOne` and a `@JoinColumn`).

For example:

```
@Entity
public class Relationship implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long relationshipId;

    @ManyToOne(...)
    @ForeignKey(name="FK_USER_ONE") //for generation only, it isn't strictly required
    @JoinColumn(name="from")
    private Long userIdFrom;

    @ManyToOne(...)
    @ForeignKey(name="FK_USER_TWO") //for generation only, it isn't strictly required
    @JoinColumn(name="to")
    private Long userIdTo;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private RelationshipStatus status;
    private LocalDate friendsRequestDate;
}
```

---

Edit:
It isn't required to specify the `@ForeignKey` annotations. They will be used if the database tables are generated automatically (ok for testing, but usually not something you'll want in production) and will create the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint on the table accordingly, but JPA mapping will work fine without it, because it takes the relationships from your defined model, not from the database itself.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I appreciate it. Is there any way to say for Spring/Hibernate: Hey, I want to create FOREIGN KEY between this entitys and PRIMARY KEY using two fields. Such as:
 
`CONSTRAINT FK_USER_ONE FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID_FROM) REFERENCES USERS (USER_ID),

    CONSTRAINT FK_USER_TWO FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID_TO) REFERENCES USERS (USER_ID),

    CONSTRAINT PK_RELATIONSHIP PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID_FROM, USER_ID_TO)`
I just want to implement it on H2 database. And problem is Spring create it. So I don't know how to specify parameters.

Comment: There is in fact a `@ForeignKey` annotation, but which isn't required other than for schema generation. I've updated my answer.